# Can a page URL differ from the file name?

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, filenames

I'm aware you can do URL rewriting for a 1-1 exchange between a custom URL and a file. But can you have 1 file map to multiple URLs?

Let's say I have a shared HTML landing page for when different clients login. Is it possible to have custom URL's which differ from the shared landing page file name for each client?

Comment: The answer is yes. Please include some code so you can have an answer in context.

Comment: I don't have any specific code at the moment as I was mostly wondering for a future project. If I pursue this, I'll try to update with some code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using routing. For instance with the following javascript plugin: https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/

Code to make it work(also available on their site):

```
//setup crossroads
crossroads.addRoute('foo');
crossroads.addRoute('lorem/ipsum');
crossroads.routed.add(console.log, console); //log all routes

//setup hasher
function parseHash(newHash, oldHash){
  crossroads.parse(newHash);
}
hasher.initialized.add(parseHash); //parse initial hash
hasher.changed.add(parseHash); //parse hash changes
hasher.init(); //start listening for history change

//update URL fragment generating new history record
hasher.setHash('lorem/ipsum');
```

This will route the urls you want to go to the page you want it to go to. Hope this helps!